# Can you get someone's Google profile picture given only their gmail address?

Tags: google-api, gmail

It seems like every api that Google has to get profile pictures requires the owner of the profile picture to be authenticated.

I did find an endpoint from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606322/retrieving-a-users-public-google-gmail-picture) stackoverflow question :

`http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/${emailAddress}?alt=json`

It does work without authentication, but it seems to only work for older email accounts, and I can't find any documentation for it in Google's docs.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: This picasa API is deprecated now