# Get user's google(gmail profile pic or google+) avatar profile image

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-plus, gmail-api, google-plus-signin

I guess Gmail API doesn't provide any way to get users profile image.

I can use Google+ API to get the url but I should have user's google+ username.

I only have user's email id and his/her account access token(gmail).

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606322/retrieving-a-users-public-google-gmail-picture) points to a url hosted by picasaweb.google.com which is discontinued now and also does not return any result for emailid of users with Gsuite account.

Answer (score 0):

If you have authenticated the user.   You should be able to use [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

response

```
"image": {
  "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAl1I/UcwPajZOuN4/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": false
 },
```

This will require that you have profile scope requested or one of these.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
```

It will also require that the user created a google+ account.  This is the only way to get the users profile picture unfortunately.

**Option two** is the people api which is linked to google contacts which may include the users profile picture if they added it. [People.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=photos
```

Also returns

```
"url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAl1I/UcwPajZOuN4/s100/photo.jpg"
```

Comment: @dalmTo I have authenticated user with gmail not with google+

Comment: @dalmTo I will not be able to use contacts with my app, is there any way to figure out how to do it with gmail endpoints.

Comment: add another scope the Gmail endpoint doesn't contain profile information.    just request an additional scope from the users