# Is it possible to get a person public profile photo using email alone, just like on the old G+/Picasa API?

Tags: android, google-plus, picasa

### Background

In the past, and in the near future, it's possible, given a person's email, to get the profile photo, as shown here:

[Retrieving a user's public google/gmail picture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25606322/878126)

It is even possible without any login to the network of G+, as shown [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46355569/878126).

### The problem

As the docs say ([**here**](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/)), this API will soon be deprecated and so it won't be possible to use it anymore:

> The Picasa Web Albums Data API will be turned off and all associated
>   OAuth scopes will be disabled. Read the deprecation notice.
>
> Key dates:
>
> - **January 2019** Unless you have requested an extension, all calls to the Picasa Web Albums Data API will begin to fail from this date
>     onwards.
> - **March 2019** The Picasa Web Albums API will be turned off. All calls to this API will fail from this date onwards and you cannot
>     request any further extensions.

### What I've found

Looking at the new API ([**migration guide**](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide_migration) and [**normal docs**](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/overview)), I don't see any similar approach to just reach a website URL and get the image of the profile. All they talk about is the photos API of Google Photos app.

What I do know is that there is the "People" API for a similar thing, but as I remember it requires a login first.

### The question

Is there an alternative API to what is currently available?

Is there a way using one of Google's APIs to get the public profile photo of a person's email address, even without login? Or maybe login is now required no matter what?

Comment: On the migration guide, it states under the features that will not be supported: `Server-to-server requests made through service accounts or anonymous requests. All requests must be authorized by a Google Photos user`, so I believe that this kind of request will not be available anymore.

Comment: @RodrigoVasconcelos That's too bad. Do you know how to use it using this API , with the authorization of "a Google Photos user" ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution I found so far is about using [people API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54181225/10806551) with your own key, But you still need to get the account id for the particular email address