# Retrieve the accountId from email in Google/GMail

Tags: google-api

I'm trying to use the [People API endpoint](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/profiles#protocol) from Google in order to load public information, but this endpoints requires the `account_id`. I only have the email of an user.

Is there an endpoint I can use to convert any @gmail.com email to the respective `account_id` that I can then load into the People API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no end point which would allow you to search by a users email address and return any information about the user.

Access to private user data would require that you authenticate the user, with profile, and email scopes where by the user can then grant your application access to their personal information.

Comment: Then how can we fetch user picture using gmail account?

Comment: @olawalejuwonm [people.get photos](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22photos%22%7D&apix=true)