# gapi.client.load() is not working in my cordova app's sign in feature

Tags: reactjs, cordova, google-api-js-client

We have an app. It does a lot. But the first thing is to sign in to get the name and picture of the user. And we have problem with it.

We have built a website in react and we used 'react-google-login' to sign in the user and get details. But, when we create the build and execute it in `cordova`, we get error as shown in the code.

```
gapi.client.load("plus","v1",apiClientLoaded),
gapi.client.plus.pepole.get({
     userId:'me'
}).execute(e)//e is another variable
```

plus should be loaded and we should be able to access people. But, "people is undefined". We have tried adding 'window' also . No change.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Thank God, Google+ is about to permanently vanish off the face of the earth, so you'll have no need to query the G+ database at all. You should mention that to whoever is making you work on a totally obsolete feature...  there are more reliable methods for Social Sign In, like the Firebase APIs.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would advise not using `gapi.client.plus` since according to google:

> Google+ APIs will be shut down on March 7, 2019. This includes Google+ Sign-in and OAuth token requests with Google+ scopes. Google+ integrations for web and mobile apps will also cease to function March 7, 2019. Learn more. This will be a progressive shutdown, with intermittent failures starting as early as January 28, 2019.

Second, The issue is probably with the client not being loaded when your `gapi.client.plus.pepole.get({ userId:'me' }).execute(e)` code is executed. Try putting this code in the `apiClientLoaded` callback that you have provided to the `gapi.client.load` function.

Comment: If google+ APIs are to be shut, what else can I be using. My ultimate aim is to get the user's profile pic and name.

Comment: well that depends..since your google plus account is shutting down, you don't have a picture there anymore. However there is a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606322/retrieving-a-users-public-google-gmail-picture

Comment: Turns out even that is being deprecated. I would recommend going through the [Google Photos API](https://developers.google.com/photos/) to solve your issue